# Figuring out weighted criteria numbers/percentages?

Tags: statistics

I'm a bit confused on how I should go about accomplishing this/unsure of the terminology.

So let's say I have a list of $10000$ voters. I want to get a composition that looks like:

$34%$ Democrats
$30%$ Republicans
$6%$  Libertarians
$30%$ Unaffiliated

$50%$ males
$50%$ females

$70%$ White
$25%$ Black
$5%$ other

So party, gender and race. I can figure out how to get numbers for gender/race but when I try to think of adding in a third set my brain turns to mush. I'd be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you assuming independence? For example, do the black voters split among the parties in the proportions specified? That makes the mathematical problem solvable, but it's probably not politically realistic.

Comment: I'm not. I'm working with a real dataset so I'd like the races to fit the parties/genders as 'naturally' as possible.

Comment: What do you mean "get a composition"?  There $4 \cdot 2 \ cdot 3=24$ categories. Are you trying to assign each of the voters to one category so the mix of parties is correct?  Trying to find a sample that has the proper mix of each characteristic?

Comment: Trying to get a sample with the proper mix.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assuming membership in a group in one category is independent of the membership in the others you can just multiply the probabilities. The probability that a voter is a Democrat, male and white is
$$
0.34 \times 0.50 \times 0.70   = 0.119
$$
(just under 12%). That's 1,190 voters in your population of 10,000. You can make the same calculations for each combination of attributes.

I don't know whether this answers your wish for "a sample with the proper mix".